# It is possible to do 'simple' binding with a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I have a user control in which I have some textblocks. I want to include this usercontrol into a listBox (or listview in case it causes any problems).

When I check the output windows, I see no binding exception, but I don't see anything in the textblock either.

Is there anyway to make this work ?

Thanks  :

Here is the listBox I use for now :

```
<ListBox AllowDrop="True"  Grid.Row="1" 
         Style="{StaticResource BaseListBox}" x:Name="LstEquipeDefaut">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <my:ucEquipe x:Name="ucEquipe" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the Usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucEquipe"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d"       
         d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="180" MinWidth="180" >
<Border Style="{StaticResource UControlBorder}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox AllowDrop="True" x:Name="TxtChiefEquipe" 
                 Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBox}" 
                 Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=chefEquipe.NomComplet}" 
                 Grid.Row="1"  />           
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Here is the objets I use :

```
Public Class Equipe

Public Property ID As Long = 0
Public Property Couleur As String = ""
Public Property Semaine As New Date(1900, 1, 1)
Public Property chefEquipe As Employe = Nothing

Public Property ListEquipeEmploye As New List(Of EquipeEmploye)
Public Property ListEquipeEquipement As New List(Of EquipeEquipement)

End Class
```

The objet Employe have a property called NomComplet. For now I manually added new objects in the listbox for testing.

Comment: Where this property `chefEquipe.NomComplet` resides?

Comment: Right... Forgot to put the objet I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Equipe` class needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

```
private Employe _chefEquipe;
public Employe ChefEquipe
{
    get { retun _chefEquipe; }
    set 
    {
        _chefEquipe = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ChefEquipe");
    }
}
```

Sorry about the C#, I don't remember the VB syntax anymore =)

Comment: Actually I found the problem. The person requesting for assistance forgot to mention the textblock was invisible in the resource file... But you're right, It's way better to implement this.